# SmatrCard logon on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: authentication, cryptography, windows-server-2008, smartcard, digital-certificate

I created a test domain, a CA and I issued a certificate with that CA. I also have fully functional CSP. For logging on, Windows are offering smart card as logon option. However, when I insert the card, after a few seconds of interaction with the card I receive the message "**no valid certificates found**". I did my homework by reading tons of MS documentation and generally whatever Google offered. Since I have no more options I'm trying here.

Added after posting: The certificate was created from the Smartcard Logon template.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I would check:

- the authentication cert asserts the windows smartcard logon OID in the EKU.
- the authenctication cert has a UPN in the subject alternative name (not stricly necessary for windows 7/server 2008).
- the authentication cert key usage is digitial signature.
- the domain controller has the certificate chain installed correctly.

How was the card issued?

*** Follow-up ***
How did the certificates make it on to the card?  AFAIK, there is no card management built into Windows, so an external card management system is needed to load the certs on the card in whatever card applet you are using.  Can you provide more specifics on the card you are trying to use?

*** Follow-up ***
You might find this link interesting; it's for PIV cards but the same ideas probably apply to your situation - the article describes a test lab setup for smart cards.  In particular, check out which certs go in which trust stores.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9427

Comment: The certificate contains OIDs for Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2) and for Smart Card Logon (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2). Subject alternative name contains:  Other Name: Principal Name=moose@mydomain.com
(Btw, moose is the user with admin privileges on mydomain.com). Key usage: Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0). What do you mean by "how was the card issued"??

Comment: Conceptually, what are you trying to accomplish?  I read your question as: issuing a certificate from a test CA, loading the certificate on to a smartcard/token, and using that card for two factor authentication on your test domain.  It appears that you have issued the certificate, how do you plan on getting that certificate onto the smartcard?  This can be pretty vendor-specific.

Comment: The certificate and the private key are on the card. That part of the story is solved. I tried deleting the certificate from the certificate store. Once I insert the card, the CSP is talking to the card. One of the things it requests from the card is the certificate. As soon as windows receives the certificate, it is stored in the certificate store again under the (Personal->Certificates). There is only one certificate on the card.

Comment: Conceptually I would like to log on to a Windows Server with the smart card.

Comment: No valid certificates found; could it be that the certificates on the card were outside their validity period (effective date to expiration date)? Is it possible to generate a chain of certificates to a trusted certificate in the certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

You may find commercial software automating the binding process but no free ones. This way you won't have to check tons of support KB.

You can get a look at this demo (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkMGXr-bls0) to see one of these tools in action.